# How to dynamically expand and populate an array of string?

Tags: c#

BigResult below has a dynamic length, how can I expand and populate string[] Dynamic?

```
string[] Dynamic = new string[] {};
for (int i=0; i<BigResult.Count(); i++)
{
    Dynamic.SetValue(BigResult[i], i++);
}
```

Comment: To use .Count() you can use objects that derive from IList

Comment: If you're looking to turn an `IEnumerable<string>` into a single string, have a look at `string.Join`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. We cannot help you with random pieces of code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't know why you think my original code is **random**, but here you go to satisfy your standard, please up-tick the arrow.

Comment: Now it's even more unclear. Why are you creating an empty array in the first place? Also, you could be just doing `BigResult.ToArray()` (supposing `BigResult` implements `IEnumerable<string>`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good question, like I said **1)** I'd like to preserve the original format rather than mash them into a big str.  **2)** length of BigResult is dynamic, so if not an empty array, what do you suggest?  **3)** I don't understand "supposing `BigResult` implements `IEnumerable<string>`. I'm not an expert of OO

Comment: So to get this straight, you just want to copy `BigResult` to the array of string (the variable named `Dynamic`)

Comment: @TheGeneral right, why didn't I think of it?

Comment: as @CamiloTerevinto said, you probably could just replace all your lines of code there with  `string[] Dynamic  = BigResult.ToArray()`

Comment: Try : string[] Dynamic = {"A", "B", "C"};

Comment: You're going to increase your chance of getting a useful answer if you help your readers understand what you are trying to do.  For example various commenters have guessed at what type `BigResult` might be because your question doesn't clearly describe `BigResult`.  If you update your question to include a [MCVE] as @Camilo suggested your readers won't have to guess at unknowns like the type of `BigResult`.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to offer a complete answer to your question because we don't know enough.  For example, we don't know the type of `BigResult`.  That said...

You don't appear to need a dynamic array in this situation.  For example, you can set the array size when you create it...

```
string[] NotDynamic = new string[BigResult.Count()];
```

If `BigResult` is a collection of strings (or some other suitable type) you can simplify things even more by using the ToArray method to create the array directly...

```
string[] Direct = BigResult.ToArray();
```

If you really need to change the size of an array after it has been instantiated you can use the [Array.Resize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize) method to create a new array of a different size and copy all the elements from old to new.  Obviously this could get expensive...

```
// O( n ) so expensive for long arrays and/or
// large array elements
Array.Resize(ref Dynamic, BigResult.Count());
```